# Query to identify the parent/child relationship between two big tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables. The first one contains laboratory result header records, one for each order. It has about 10 million rows in it that contain one of about 6,000 unique ProcedureIDs...

```
OrderID
ResultID
ProcedureID
ProcedureName
OrderDate
ResultDate
PatientID
ProviderID
```

The second table contains the detailed result record(s) for each order in the first table. It has about 80 million rows and contains about 28,000 child components that are associated with the 6,000 procedure IDs from the first table.

```
ResultComponentID
ResultID (foreign key to first table)
ComponentID
ComponentName
ResultValueType
ResultValue
ResultUnits
ResultingLab
```

I have a subset (n=135) procedure IDs for which I need a list of associated child component IDs. Here is a simple example...

```
Table 1
1000|1|CBC|Complete Blood Count|8/1/2019 08:00:00|8/2/2019 09:27:00|9999|8888
1001|2|CA|Calcium|8/1/2019 08:01:00|8/2/2019 09:28:00|9999|8888

Table 2
2543|1|RBC|Red Blood Cell Count|NM|60|Million/uL|OurLab
2544|1|PLT|Platelet Count|NM|60|Thou/cmm|OurLab
2545|2|RBC|Red Blood Cell Count|NM|60|Million/uL|OurLab
2546|1|CA|Calcium|NM|40|g/dl|OurLab
```

In this example, if CBC was in my subset and CA wasn't, I would expect two rows back...

```
CBC|Complete Blood Count|RBC|Red Blood Cell Count
CBC|Complete Blood Count|PLT|Platelet Count
```

Even if I had two million CBCs in the DB, I only need have one set of CBC parent/child rows.

If I were using a scripting tool, I would use a for each loop to iterate through the subset and grab the top 1 of each ProcedureID and use it to get the associated component children.

If I really wanted to go crazy with this, I would not assume that CBC only had two components, as some labs might send us two and some might send us seven.

Any advice on how to get the list of parent/child associations?

Answer (score 0):

For the simple query, sometimes there is no way around just writing out all 135 ids if you can't find a neat way to get that subset out of a query or store it in a temp table.

For the uniqueness requirement, just add a 'group by'

```
Select t1.ProcedureId, t2.ComponentId
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t2.ResultId = t1.ResultId
where t1.ProcedureId in (
'CBC',
'etc', -- 135 times...
)
group by t1.ProcedureId, t2.ComponentId
```

Comment: This seems like it would work, but it doesn't because the query finds all the matching records (millions) and then tries to group them, bringing the data warehouse to its knees. There has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: There are lots of different ways.  You can be as efficient as you want. Besides the query, it also depends on your warehouse design and indexes.  What you probably want to search for is CROSS APPLY.  remove the 'group by', and replace the line 'join...' with something like  'cross apply (select top 1 ComponentId from Table2 where resultId = t1.ResultId order by 1) t2'